# Why doesn't join elimination work with sys.query_store_plan?

Tags: sql-server, performance, join, execution-plan, query-store, query-performance

The following is a simplification of a performance problem encountered with the Query Store:

```
CREATE TABLE #tears
(
    plan_id bigint NOT NULL
);

INSERT #tears (plan_id) 
VALUES (1);

SELECT
    T.plan_id
FROM #tears AS T
LEFT JOIN sys.query_store_plan AS QSP
    ON QSP.plan_id = T.plan_id;
```

The `plan_id` column is documented as being the primary key of [`sys.query_store_plan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-query-store-plan-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), but the execution plan does not use [join elimination](https://blogs.msmvps.com/robfarley/2008/11/08/join-simplification-in-sql-server/) as would be expected:

1. No attributes are being projected from the DMV.
2. The DMV primary key `plan_id` cannot duplicate rows from the temporary table
3. A `LEFT JOIN` is used, so no rows from `T` can be eliminated.

[Execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HyObYM_w7)

[image: plan graphic]

Why is this, and what can be done to obtain join elimination here?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The documentation is a little misleading. The DMV is a non-materialized view, and does not have a primary key as such. The underlying definitions are a little complex but a simplified definition of `sys.query_store_plan` is:

```
CREATE VIEW sys.query_store_plan AS
SELECT
    PPM.plan_id
    -- various other attributes
FROM sys.plan_persist_plan_merged AS PPM
LEFT JOIN sys.syspalvalues AS P
    ON P.class = 'PFT' 
    AND P.[value] = plan_forcing_type;
```

Further, `sys.plan_persist_plan_merged` is also a view, though one needs to connect via the Dedicated Administrator Connection to see its definition. Again, simplified:

```
CREATE VIEW sys.plan_persist_plan_merged AS   
SELECT     
    P.plan_id as plan_id,    
    -- various other attributes
FROM sys.plan_persist_plan P 
    -- NOTE - in order to prevent potential deadlock
    -- between QDS_STATEMENT_STABILITY LOCK and index locks   
    WITH (NOLOCK) 
LEFT JOIN sys.plan_persist_plan_in_memory PM
    ON P.plan_id = PM.plan_id;
```

The indexes on `sys.plan_persist_plan` are:

```
╔════════════════════════╦══════════════════════════════════════╦═════════════╗
║       index_name       ║          index_description           ║ index_keys  ║
╠════════════════════════╬══════════════════════════════════════╬═════════════╣
║ plan_persist_plan_cidx ║ clustered, unique located on PRIMARY ║ plan_id     ║
║ plan_persist_plan_idx1 ║ nonclustered located on PRIMARY      ║ query_id(-) ║
╚════════════════════════╩══════════════════════════════════════╩═════════════╝
```

So `plan_id` is constrained to be unique on `sys.plan_persist_plan`.

Now, `sys.plan_persist_plan_in_memory` is a streaming table-valued function, presenting a tabular view of data only held in internal memory structures. As such, it does not have any unique constraints.

At heart, the query being executed is therefore equivalent to:

```
DECLARE @t1 table (plan_id integer NOT NULL);
DECLARE @t2 table (plan_id integer NOT NULL UNIQUE CLUSTERED);
DECLARE @t3 table (plan_id integer NULL);

SELECT 
    T1.plan_id
FROM @t1 AS T1 
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT 
        T2.plan_id
    FROM @t2 AS T2
    LEFT JOIN @t3 AS T3 
        ON T3.plan_id = T2.plan_id
) AS Q1
    ON Q1.plan_id = T1.plan_id;
```

...which does not produce join elimination:

[image]

Getting right to the core of the issue, the problem is the inner query:

```
DECLARE @t2 table (plan_id integer NOT NULL UNIQUE CLUSTERED);
DECLARE @t3 table (plan_id integer NULL);

SELECT 
    T2.plan_id
FROM @t2 AS T2
LEFT JOIN @t3 AS T3 
    ON T3.plan_id = T2.plan_id;
```

...clearly the left join might result in rows from `@t2` being duplicated because `@t3` has no uniqueness constraint on `plan_id`. Therefore, the join cannot be eliminated:

[image]

To workaround this, we can explicitly tell the optimizer that we do not require any duplicate `plan_id` values:

```
DECLARE @t2 table (plan_id integer NOT NULL UNIQUE CLUSTERED);
DECLARE @t3 table (plan_id integer NULL);

SELECT DISTINCT
    T2.plan_id
FROM @t2 AS T2
LEFT JOIN @t3 AS T3 
    ON T3.plan_id = T2.plan_id;
```

The outer join to `@t3` can now be eliminated:

[image]

Applying that to the real query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    T.plan_id
FROM #tears AS T
LEFT JOIN sys.query_store_plan AS QSP
    ON QSP.plan_id = T.plan_id;
```

Equally, we could add `GROUP BY T.plan_id` instead of the `DISTINCT`. Anyway, the optimizer can now correctly reason about the `plan_id` attribute all the way down through the nested views, and eliminate both outer joins as desired:

[image]

Note that making `plan_id` unique in the temporary table would not be sufficient to obtain join elimination, since it would not preclude incorrect results. We must explicitly reject duplicate `plan_id` values from the final result to allow the optimizer to work its magic here.